# Small gnats in roach colony

Tags: bearded-dragon, pest-control, insects, terrariums, live-food

I have a small Dubai roach colony for my three bearded dragons. I have small little gnat-like bugs that will flock to the colony every week or so. It's not so bad as to affect the colony or the house per se, but it is a little annoying to just have small gnats flying about. I'm wondering what these bugs are and if there is anything I can do to prevent them?

As a side note, I regularly feed the roaches about twice a week and remove dead bodies every time I go to feed the lizards insects which is several times a week.

Comment: May you have a picture of them? This would help a lot to identify them :) without we could only guess...